# Can't upload images to Imgur for a 400 forbidden response

Tags: imgur

I can't upload images to my imgur account for a 400 forbidden response.

I tried many times to upload images to my Imgur account in China, but failed all the time with a 400 response. Like,

```
{
    "data": {
        "error": "These actions are forbidden."
    },
    "success": false,
    "status": 400
}
```

Here is my steps,

1. Register an application

(1)  Request https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient in browser, then add a callback redirect URL.

(2)  Getting client id and secret.

2. Do authorization and get token

In "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2", it shows three response_type like code, token, and pin.
But I can and only can use token type to get access token and refresh token directly.If I use code or pin type to do authorization and then request token with postman, got a 400 error, "These actions are forbidden."
So Here is what I request an access code using response_type with token.

(1)  Enter the following URL in the web browser and allow the application to connect with my account.
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxxx&state=state

(2)  Then get access token and refresh token in the redirect URL,
https://app.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback?state=state#access_token=xxx&expires_in=315360000&token_type=bearer&refresh_token=xxx&account_username=xxx&account_id=xxx

3. Upload image

(1)  Until now, I can simply use postman to upload an image.

(2)  The relative curl command generated by postman like.
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.imgur.com/3/image \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
  --header 'Postman-Token: 7edabb12-7f1f-4f30-9e9b-e87ad1cae0ee' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  --form image=@/xxx/xxx/IMG_3310.JPG

I tried to upload images with different size, in different machines, using different IP addresses in China or the USA, but failed.
I also don't know why I cann't using code or pin to exchange token.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your images are **too large.**

I've been trying to upload a 12MB GIF on there and it always gave back 400. Then I tried cutting it and then uploading another under 5.7MB size, and it worked.

I'd suggest looking into the territory of what imgur supports and allows as content, not just authentication and stuff.